macOS 14.6.1 : Mouse behaviors - Logitech wired and Magic Mouse controlled by the same settings
I have been useing a wired Logitech USB mouse for a couple years and all of a sudden it decided to slow way down. Thinking this was a preferences issue. Settings > Mouse, cranked the speed up to Max. Still slower than I would like. Break out the magic mouse, and it moves the cursor across the screen by tapping it.
So I have a standard USB mouse that is suddenly a slug and an Apple Magic Missle... Both of these devices are seemingly governed by a single preferences panel. Ostensibly stored in a .plist
Searches on this site state the file is ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
moving the file to ~/Users/brap/Desktop to save it off and letting the OS re-create the file still yields the same result. Wired slug and bluetooth rocket.
People have suggested that I should contact Logitech - that its a hardware issue and not software. Which might make sense if the devices behavior had not suddenly changed two days ago.
I will be taking my mouse to the local box retail store to see if I can replicate the issue on one of their devices.
Hopefully someone can give me an idea on what to try next that is not : back up everything and re-install from scratch. Do any of you know any more about the Preferences and plists? Is there something I am overlooking?
Best.

First, a full macOS reinstall seems a very brutal way of trying to solve a mouse speed issue - I can't really believe that this is the best approach or even a solution. Check that the magic mouse performs as expected, i.e. when turning down the speed, does that make it move slower? If so, then the Logitech mouse is most likely the problem. Also (while unclear to me how exactly this could be the problem), try different USB ports and if possible a different cable, but I assume this is hardwired to the mouse.

I agree. and I am not sure it would make a difference. I went to the big box store and plugged into one of their m3 iMacs and replicated the problem exactly. Like i explained to apple, this appears to be an OS issue. with 14.6.1 (23G93).
The magic mouse works. and the tracking speed works 'normally'. I disagree with the assertion that the wired USB 2 mouse suddenly on some hardware level decided that it was going to operate at half speed. If it has always been like that, then yeah ok. But this anomaly just cropped up a few days ago.

System Preferences > Mouse > Advanced > Pointer Acceleration [Off]
System Preferences > Mouse > Tracking Speed . and here play whith it.
